# SQL Server show invalid column name when the column name on the table exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The error message showed error invalid column name when the column actually exists in the created table.

```
CREATE TABLE Worker (
    WORKER_ID INT NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME CHAR(25),
    LAST_NAME CHAR(25),
    SALARY INT,
    JOINING_DATE DATETIME,
    DEPARTMENT CHAR(25)
);

INSERT INTO Worker 
(WORKER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY, JOINING_DATE, DEPARTMENT) VALUES
        (001, 'Monika', 'Arora', 100000, '14-02-20 09.00.00', 'HR'),
        (002, 'Niharika', 'Verma', 80000, '14-06-11 09.00.00', 'Admin'),
        (003, 'Vishal', 'Singhal', 300000, '14-02-20 09.00.00', 'HR'),
        (004, 'Amitabh', 'Singh', 500000, '14-02-20 09.00.00', 'Admin'),
        (005, 'Vivek', 'Bhati', 500000, '14-06-11 09.00.00', 'Admin'),
        (006, 'Vipul', 'Diwan', 200000, '14-06-11 09.00.00', 'Account'),
        (007, 'Satish', 'Kumar', 75000, '14-01-20 09.00.00', 'Account'),
        (008, 'Geetika', 'Chauhan', 90000, '14-04-11 09.00.00', 'Admin');
```

I have succesfully created the table, I didn't see any typo in the column name. This code is copied from https://www.techbeamers.com/sql-query-questions-answers-for-practice/.

[image]

So when I hover the column name it provides "Invalid column name 'FIRST NAME'" and the rest of the column gives the same error message

Another problem is when I try to execute the code, it gives:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 17 Invalid object name 'Worker'.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share the error message as well?

Comment: `Invalid object name 'Worker'` means the table `Worker` doesn't exists. Because there is `DROP TABLE Worker` it Deletes the table.

Comment: I agree with @PrebenHuybrechts write the DROP statement before Create. Use DROP TABLE IF EXISTS.

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2020.

Comment: When you posted your code, you did not post all the relevant parts of your code. Please, do not rely on anyone to find out what is wrong from an image. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please edit in the code you missed.

Comment: You should NOT be using the MASTER database for your own work. Before you really create a huge problem in a critical system database, create your own database and use it for learning/development work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `DROP` statement before the insert. That's why you get an warning that the column is missing.

You may want to move the `DROP` statement before the `CREATE` one, or even use the new syntax `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ...` if it is available in your edition.

Comment: I execute the query separately, FIrstly, I executed the create table, then I execute the insert table. Then, I execute the drop table separately as if it was a rollback. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing invalid datetime during the insert.
It should be like as below:

```
INSERT INTO Worker 
(WORKER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY, JOINING_DATE, DEPARTMENT) VALUES
        (001, 'Monika', 'Arora', 100000, '2000-02-14 09:00:00', 'HR')
```